# Zend 2 TableGateway conundrum?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have these 2 pieces of code... In MY head, they are identical, but one works and one doesn't. Hoping someone can help me figure this out.

This code doesn't work. It returns the entire table, ignoring the orderby and the limit.

```
public function getNews($limit = null)
{
    $select = new Select();

    $select->order('Date DESC');
    if($limit != null)
    {
        $select->limit($limit);
    }

    $result = $this->gateway->select($select);
    return $result;
}
```

This code is rearranged to use an anonymous function and works perfectly.

```
public function getNews($limit = null)
{
    $result = $this->gateway->select(
        function(Select $select) use ($limit)
        {
            $select->order('Date DESC');
            if($limit != null)
            {
                $select->limit($limit);
            }
        }
    );

    return $result;
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: iirc 2nd function should return a select * n nothing less, as the anonymous function doesn't return anything

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? These are, for all intents and purposes identical snippets of code. The one that doesn't work does not throw an error, it just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

The second way is how the `TableGateway::select` method is meant to be used. You either pass it a simple array of where predicates or a `Closure` that then performs more complex operations on the `Select` object.

Check out the [documentation on TableGateway](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html#basic-usage) for more details.